# Nonvanishing Gradient of a harmonic polynomial

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, harmonic-functions, fundamental-solution

Let $e$ be a unit vector in $\mathbb R^d$, $d\geq 3$. Consider the function $\Gamma(x):=\frac {1}{|x-e|^{d-2}}$, which is the (translated) fundamental solution to the Laplacian on $\mathbb R^d$. Let $Z_n(x)$, $n\geq 2$ be the degree $n$ homogeneous term in the Taylor expansion of $\Gamma(x)$ at $x=0$. Show that $\nabla Z_n(x)$ vanishes at the origin but not elsewhere.

The problem is found in Wolff's article: *Note on counterexamples in strong unique continuation problems*

http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1992-114-02/S0002-9939-1992-1014648-2/S0002-9939-1992-1014648-2.pdf

His arguments were "Since $Z_n(\frac {x}{|x|})$ is a solution to a second order ODE, $\nabla Z_n$ vanishes only at 0." I got completely lost in this sentence.

Comment: It's amazing, indeed.